# Borrar elementos de un array - Sólo borra el primero. - Javascript

Tags: javascript

**¿Por qué me borra el primer elemento de una lista/array de objetos?**

Os pongo en contexto, tengo un formulario para agregar Discos. Inserto tantos discos como quiera:

- Disco1
- Disco2
- Disco3

Me pongo en un campo input de tipo text para poder eliminar un disco existente, inserto el nombre "Disco2" y me dice que NO existe, pero si inserto "Disco1" lo borra correctamente.

Seguidamente tendría los elementos:

- Disco2
- Disco3

Me pongo en un campo input de tipo text para poder eliminar un disco existente, inserto el nombre "Disco3" y me dice que NO existe, pero si inserto "Disco2" lo borra correctamente.

Seguidamente tendría el elemento:

- Disco3

¿Por qué sólo me deja borrar el primero? **¿Algún error en el "splice"?**

Función Javascript:

```
//Elimina el disco cuyo nombre coincide con el que se pasa como parametro.
    this.deleteDisco = function (nombre){
        for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
            if(this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre == nombre){
                this.arrayDiscos.splice(i,1);
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si pones el else dentro del for nunca preguntas más lejos del primer elemento de la lista. Devuelve false cuando recorra todos los elementos:

```
//Elimina el disco cuyo nombre coincide con el que se pasa como parametro.
this.deleteDisco = function (nombre){
    for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
        if(this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre == nombre){
            this.arrayDiscos.splice(i,1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Joder, claro! @omaza1990, es que le estuve ayudando, y de hecho creo que eso se lo dije yo, vaya cagada, perdon amigo T.T

Comment: El problema está en que cuando me queda solamente un elemento no lo borra...